# Can I inherit a class with the same name and use it freely in other units without a unit prefix?

Tags: delphi, class, inheritance, overriding, delphi-xe2

Suppose I want to override some class which is already defined somewhere, for example, let's say `System.Classes.TOriginalClass`, and I want to keep the original class name. I know I will have to define it something like this:

```
type
  TOriginalClass = class(System.Classes.TOriginalClass)
  ...
  end;
```

If I wanted to implement this custom overridden class within the same unit where it was declared, I don't have any problem, so long as every place where I want it used is Below where I declared this class.

But suppose I want to use this replacement class in another unit. `System.Classes` is an extremely common unit, which is used in almost every other unit of mine. I would like to be able to use both the `System.Classes` unit as well as the unit where I have created this overridden version, let's call it `MyClasses`.

I know that in any other unit, I could accomplish this by including the full unit/class in the declaration, like so:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(MyClasses.TOriginalClass)
  ...
  end;
```

But, that would pretty much defeat the whole purpose, because I would be forced to include `MyClasses.` as a prefix before the `TOriginalClass`. What I would like to do is not have to worry about where `TOriginalClass` was originally declared, and declare it like this...

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TOriginalClass)
  ...
  end;
```

...while being sure that `TMyClass` will be inherited from `MyClasses.TOriginalClass` instead of `System.Classes.TOriginalClass`.

I'm pretty sure this will consist of the order in which I declare each of these two units in the uses clause, for example, using `System.Classes` before using `MyClasses`. But is this supposed to be possible? What should I be aware of when doing this?

PS - `TOriginalClass` I know isn't a real class, I'm using it to demonstrate *any* class which was originally declared in `System.Classes`. The same should apply for any original class in any unit.

Comment: Actually, would it be more proper to call it a "Namespace Prefix" than a "Unit Prefix"?

Comment: I believe what you want is an "Interceptor class" - see http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/interceptor.htm for example.

Comment: @Gerry: indeed, that was my first thought too. But a unit with an interceptor classes must always be "used" later than the unit of original class. Interception relies on the fact that the class is not qualified by its unit/namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already gave the answers.

Yes, you can derive from `MyClasses.TOriginalClass` by only specifying `TOriginalClass`, but it requires that `MyClasses` comes later in the `uses` list than `System.Classes`, or that `System.Classes` is omitted from the `uses` list altogether. There is no other way, sorry.

If you don't qualify `TOriginalClass`, the compiler will use the "last" declaration it encountered. It will not automatically use the most derived one.

Sorry.

Comment: +1, thanks, I was assuming this was how it had to be, didn't know any facts. I just wanted to make sure this is *supposed* to be possible and whether or not to expect any issues.